# Why are these thermal expansion equations valid only for small changes in temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics

I know that the empirically derived equations$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}L & = x \, {L}_{0} \, \mathrm{d}T  \tag{1}  \\[5px]
\mathrm{d}V & = y \, {V}_{0} \, \mathrm{d}T \,,  \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$where $x$ and $y$ are coefficients, describe the relationship between the change in length, $\mathrm{d}L ,$ and the change in volume, $\mathrm{d}V ,$ of a material.

**Question:**  Why are these equations valid only if $\mathrm{d}T$ has a small value?

Comment: The coefficients x and y are weak functions of temperature.

Comment: @ChesterMiller could you clarify that please?

Comment: The coefficient of volumetric thermal expansion and the coefficient of liner thermal expansion are typically observed to be weak functions of temperature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the reasons why these equations are valid for small range of temperature is that these equations derived from approximating the original equations.

The original/complete equation involves an exponential function. For getting to these equations, we use the Taylor series expansion of $e^t ,$ where $t$ is very small, here instead of $t,$ we have $x \, \mathrm{d}T$ as the power of $e.$ Since Taylor series expansion is nearly accurate only when its power is small, $x \, \mathrm{d}T$ should be small and hence this works only for small range of $\mathrm{d}T.$

If you want the complete equation, here it is:$$
L ~=~ {L}_{0} \, {e}^{x \left( T - {T}_{0} \right)}
\, .
$$Here,

- ${L}_{0}$ is length at temperature ${T}_{0} ;$
- $L$ is the length at $T ;$ and
- $x$ is the coefficient of linear expansion.

So, the equation you are using comes from approximating this above equation when $x \, \mathrm{d}T$ is small.